# Python; Get the length of a dictionary as a value in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

I would add a value in my dictionary that contains the length of the dictionary like:

So I basically tried

```py
{..., 'commands' : len(dict) + ' commands are available'}
```

but it retruns me a `NameError: name 'dict' is not defined`

I tried also

```py
def dict_len():
     return len(dict)
{..., 'commands' : dict_len() + ' commands are available'}
```

but also:  `NameError: name 'dict' is not defined`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The problem in both attempts is that you have no variable (dictionary or otherwise) whose name is `dict`. If you mean the number of keys, try `len(d)` where `d` is actually the name of a `dict` variable.

Comment: But why? If you need the dictionary to have business logic you should probably be using an _object_ instead. This is especially true if you want the length in `d['commands']` to change if you modify the dictionary.

Comment: Here the name is of the dict is 'dict' for make it simple but I've understand

Comment: Other people have given correct answers for you, but I would like to just point out that this is a bad idea since the length data in the dict can easily become out of date. Its too easy to add another entry to the dictionary while forgetting too update the length counter.

Comment: Yes but here the dict is used only to contains a lot of function and avoid  the very long elif structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's already a class so don't overwrite it.

Secondly, how you want to do this is save your dictionary first like so

```
my_dict = {...} # put whatever values you have in here
```

Then do

```
my_dict["commands"] = str(len(my_dict)) + " commands are available"
```

Comment: Yes ! Thanks you

Comment: @Edhyjox don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: I use 'dict' name for example and be more simple

Comment: Yes but I got 8 more minutes to wait before I can accept

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing parameters to the function you defined

```
def len_dict(dict):
       return len(dict)
```

That's how you have to use the functions.

I think you need to go through the basics of python.

Comment: You shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name, as it is already the name of the `dict` class

Comment: It's not dict, here is for the example

Comment: @PraveenSms, If I do this I goet NameError